# Arc length $\gamma(t) = (30 \sin t, 30 \cos t, 50 \cos t)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate the arc length of the curve

$$\gamma (t) = ( 30 \sin t, 30 \cos t, 50 \cos t)$$

**My attempt:**

$L = \int | \gamma'(t) | dt = \int \sqrt{ 30^2 \cos^2 t + 30^2 \sin^2 t + 50^2 \sin^2 t} \;dt = \int \sqrt{(50^2 + 30^2)(1) - 50^2 \cos^2 t} \;dt$

But I couldnt solve this integral. Can't it be expressed in terms of elementary functions or I made something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The result of your antiderivative is an elliptic integral
$$\int \sqrt{ 30^2 \cos^2 t + 30^2 \sin^2 t + 50^2 \sin^2 t} \;dt =30 E\left(t\left|-\frac{25}{9}\right.\right) $$ which cannot be simplified.